# Which is the best method to get a local file URI and save it online?

Tags: rest, web-applications, synchronization, local-storage

I'm working on a **web project** but the scenario has some restrictions for a specific user case. We have been investigating a web-only solution and a dropbox-like native way to solve this.

The **main restriction** is that we **shouldn't upload local files to a cloud**. We can only track local URI's.

**The use cases are:**

- As a developer, I should be able to link the URI of a local file to a webapp. Thus, I can click on a webapp element and the local file should be opened.
- As a user, I should be able to add a directory and view the same structure on the webapp (clicking opens the file). The files are not uploaded.

**Possible solutions:**

- We started trying the FileSystem API but when the specs. were fully defined, we figured out that a local sandbox was not enough, and we can't access to the local URI due to security issues.
- We are considering a Dropbox-like native app. The [Invision Sync App](http://blog.invisionapp.com/invision-sync/) is closer to what we want.
- The less optimal solution would be a complete native application.

**The question:**

Which is the more efficient way to achieve this? Any idea on some native libraries for doing this faster? Any web-only workaround?

Thanks in advance.